# Input field is not working

Tags: forms, reactjs, input, jsx

When I am using `state` variable as a value for the `input` fields, second `input` field is not working.

Here is the code:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    className="form-control" 
    placeholder="mobileNumber" 
    onChange={this.handleLoginMobileNumber} 
    onKeyUp={this.handleLoginMobileNumber} 
    value={this.state.loginMobileNumber} 
/>

<input 
    type="text" 
    className="form-control" 
    placeholder="Passcode" 
    maxLength="4" 
    value={this.state.loginPasscode}
/>
<br/>
<button 
    className="btn btn-large btn-primary medata-login-form-input medata-login-form-submit-button" 
    onClick={this.submitLogin}>
    Log in
</button>
```

Help me, Thanks.

Comment: can you show the whole component code?

Comment: instead of value="" use defaultValue="" and it must work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is, you are using [Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and you forgot to define the `onChange` method and update the `state` value with password field, because of that password field is **read only**.

Check this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {
          loginMobileNumber: '', 
          loginPasscode: ''
     }
  }
  
  handleLoginMobileNumber(e){
     this.setState({loginMobileNumber: e.target.value})
  }
  
  loginPasscode(e){
     this.setState({loginPasscode: e.target.password})
  }
  
  render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                className="form-control" 
                placeholder="mobileNumber" 
                onChange={this.handleLoginMobileNumber.bind(this)}
                value={this.state.loginMobileNumber} 
            />

            <input 
                type="password" 
                className="form-control" 
                placeholder="Passcode" 
                maxLength="4" 
                value={this.state.loginPasscode}
                onChange={this.loginPasscode.bind(this)}
            />
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Got it Thanks @Mayank Shukla